# How to make a basic spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to make a basic spring boot application.

Steps I followed - > File - > New -> Spring Starter Project.

I got the below mentioned error by doing so.

[image]

What should I do?

This is what the eclipse error log file look like : [image]

Comment: No connection. Maybe you need a proxy? Or just create the project here: [https://start.spring.io/](https://start.spring.io/)

Comment: It says there is a more detailed message in the Eclipse error log.  What is that message?

Comment: @Patrick:  I just saw you also suggested the proxy and/or that he opens the website... My answers ends up being a ripoff of your comment :)  =>  I converted the answer to a community wiki.

Comment: @Patrick yes creating the project at https://start.spring.io/ worked for me. But I wanted to know why it is not working through sts itself.

Comment: @RobBaily where do we see the eclipse error log?

Comment: Do you need a proxy for internet connections? If not try to  reinstall sts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also suggested by **@Patrick** (this is a `community wiki answer`):

#### Spring Test Suite

You should take a look at the proxy settings.

### Alternative

You can also open the website yourself:

```
http://start.spring.io/
```

[image]

Click `Generate Project` to downloads the project (zipped).